# Songs got deleted and don't know how.

Tags: downloading

I download a lot of songs on my phone which have been there for a long time and just the other day I went to play something and it said no songs playing? I didn't delete anything either. Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: Did you get any kind of error message ?

Comment: No :( I even tried downloading new songs and they wouldn't come up on my playlist.

Comment: Also, which app do you use for music playback? Where was the music stored - internal memory, SD Card?